# Develop commercial application based on MapBox

Tags: unity-game-engine, xamarin.forms, mapbox

We are in the initial design phase and soon starting prototyping a MapBox -based application, not a game, for IOS and Android with a server backend.

Given the characteristics of Unity3d I would like some advise if that is an optimal platform to develop a commercial non-game application on. Reason for initial Unity3d discussion is that the current developer team all have skills on Unity.

We have been looking at xamarine-forms, which we have no experience of, as a possible alternative.

We would really appreciate some advise, experiences etc. regarding the platform of choice.

Answer (score 0):

Well that will depend on your needs, keep in mind that Mapbox have SDK's for multiple frameworks, like Unity.

Like everything, Unity have pros and cons:

Pros:

1. Easy UI development
2. If your app is 3D heavy, will be easy to handle, like audio,
   animations etc
3. Easy to export on multiplatform
4. Easy AR/VR integration

Cons:

1. Heavy battery drain
2. Adds like 25MB by default to the app size
3. If you use multiple native features you will have to code several
   plugins for each platform
4. There are no default UI native components

I'll update the answer if I remember more!